# c# How do I add 'Authorization: Basic' to my HttpClient header?

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest

I'm trying to send GET method to a web REST api and it requires authorization in this form:

```
Authorization: Basic <Base64 value of UTF-8 encoded “username:password”>
```

This request gives me:

`Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).`

Code:

```
try
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.BaseAddress = bUrl; // https url
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-type", "application/xml");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + uAuth);
    HttpResponseMessage XmlResponse = await client.GetAsync(url);
    XmlResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    string xml = await XmlResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Debug.WriteLine(xml);
}
catch (HttpRequestException hre) {
    Debug.WriteLine(hre.ToString());
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
```

While `uAuth` is just a `Base64` `Username:Password` representation:

```
string uAuth =
            Convert.ToBase64String(
            Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("username:password")
            );
```

Am I doing something wrong?

edit:
Tried also with:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", uAuth);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be an `Authorization` property on `DefaultRequestHeaders` that you can use:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", uAuth);
```

Comment: this does work.  have you checked that the header exists using Fiddler?  Could be that the username or password data is incorrect.

Comment: I didn't use fiddler, but when I don't add Authorization, it just returns 500 (Internal Server Error), so it is there. Yes, username and password is good :/

Comment: Try a raw post from a tool like Postman.  Just to valid your assumptions.

Comment: Ah, ok, nevermind. I was trying to use the pinnaclesports odds API, but now I can see there's a note that account must be funded (lol). Both answers are right :)